# How to convert a single date column into three individual columns (y, m, d)?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a large dataset with thousands of dates in the `ymd` format. I want to convert this column so that way there are three individual columns by year, month, and day. There are literally thousands of dates so I am trying to do this with a single code for the entire dataset.

Comment: please post the output of `dput(head(my_data))` inside your question.

Comment: Are the dates stored as `20170131` or have you already parsed them in to R using `lubridate::ymd()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract date elements from POSIXlt and put into data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126537/extract-date-elements-from-posixlt-and-put-into-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9749598/5325862

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` extractors in *lubridate* for this. Here's an example:

```
library('dplyr')
library('tibble')
library('lubridate')

## create some data
df <- tibble(date = seq(ymd(20190101), ymd(20191231), by = '7 days'))
```

which yields

```
> df
# A tibble: 53 x 1
   date      
   <date>    
 1 2019-01-01
 2 2019-01-08
 3 2019-01-15
 4 2019-01-22
 5 2019-01-29
 6 2019-02-05
 7 2019-02-12
 8 2019-02-19
 9 2019-02-26
10 2019-03-05
# … with 43 more rows
```

Then `mutate` `df` using the relevant extractor function:

```
df <- mutate(df,
             year  = year(date),
             month = month(date),
             day   = day(date))
```

This results in:

```
> df
# A tibble: 53 x 4
   date        year month   day
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 2019-01-01  2019     1     1
 2 2019-01-08  2019     1     8
 3 2019-01-15  2019     1    15
 4 2019-01-22  2019     1    22
 5 2019-01-29  2019     1    29
 6 2019-02-05  2019     2     5
 7 2019-02-12  2019     2    12
 8 2019-02-19  2019     2    19
 9 2019-02-26  2019     2    26
10 2019-03-05  2019     3     5
# … with 43 more rows
```

If you only want the new three columns, use `transmute()` instead of `mutate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate` but without having to specify a separator:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(d = c('2019/3/18','2018/10/29'))
df %>%
  mutate(
    date = lubridate::ymd(d),
    year = lubridate::year(date),
    month = lubridate::month(date),
    day = lubridate::day(date)
  )
```

Note that you can change the first entry from ymd to fit other formats.

Answer (score 1):

A slighlty different `tidyverse` solution that requires less code could be:

**Code**

```
tibble(date = "2018-05-01") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(date), lst(year, month, day))
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  date        year month   day
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 2018-05-01  2018     5     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Data
d = data.frame(date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2012/03/04"))

library(lubridate)    

cbind(d,
      read.table(header = FALSE,
                 sep = "-",
                 text = as.character(ymd(d$date))))
#        date   V1 V2 V3
#1 2019-01-01 2019  1  1
#2 2019-02-01 2019  2  1
#3 2012/03/04 2012  3  4
```

OR

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
d %>%
    mutate(date2 = as.character(ymd(date))) %>%
    separate(date2, c("year", "month", "day"), "-")
#        date year month day
#1 2019-01-01 2019    01  01
#2 2019-02-01 2019    02  01
#3 2012/03/04 2012    03  04
```